# DataBase in MuleESB (not in application)

Tags: database, mule

Is it possible to create DataBase in MuleESB but not in my application (project) ? I mean - when I delete project database will still exist. DataBase in other server , for example MySql is not a solution for my problem.

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Your best call would be to deploy an different application to the one you mention containing an H2 database or similar, using a persistent file in your hard-disk. Although that is not something I would do or recommend.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i decided to use just MongoDB on separate server.